# SQL Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Below is the procedure.  I keep getting SQL Must declare the scalar variable "@sql" even though i have converted @startdate to varchar.  What am i missing?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[project_revenue_forecast_monthly]
@startDate datetime,
@sql varchar(max)
AS

SET @sql = 'SELECT CLIENTNAME, PROJECTNAME, PROJECTSD, 
    isnull([' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, @startDate, 13), 4, 8), ' ', '') + '],0) as
      [' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, @startDate, 13), 4, 8), ' ', '') + '], 
    isnull([' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @startDate), 13), 4, 8), ' ', '') + '],0) as  
      [' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @startDate), 13), 4, 8), ' ', '') + '],
    isnull([' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 2, @startDate), 13), 4, 8), ' ', '') + '],0) as  
      [' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 2, @startDate), 13), 4, 8), ' ', '') + '],
    isnull([' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 3, @startDate), 13), 4, 8), ' ', '') + '],0) as  
      [' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 3, @startDate), 13), 4, 8), ' ', '') + '],
    isnull([' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 4, @startDate), 13), 4, 8), ' ', '') + '],0) as  
      [' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 4, @startDate), 13), 4, 8), ' ', '') + '],
    isnull([' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 5, @startDate),  13), 4, 8), ' ', '') + '],0) as  
      [' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 5, @startDate), 13), 4, 8), ' ', '') + '],
    FORECASTTIMEDAYS, BILLINGRATEDAILY
    FROM
      (
      SELECT
        CLIENTNAME, PROJECTNAME, PROJECTS, SCHENTRYDATE, FORECASTTOTAL
      FROM viewprojscheduling_group
      ) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
      (
      SUM(FORECASTTOTAL)
      FOR SCHENTRYDATE IN (' +
              QUOTENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, @startDate, 13), 4, 8), ' ', '')) + ', ' +
              QUOTENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @startDate), 13), 4, 8), ' ', '')) + ', ' +
              QUOTENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 2, @startDate), 13), 4, 8), ' ', '')) + ', ' +
              QUOTENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 3, @startDate), 13), 4, 8), ' ', '')) + ', ' +
              QUOTENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 4, @startDate), 13), 4, 8), ' ', '')) + ', ' +
              QUOTENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(MONTH, 5, @startDate), 13), 4, 8), ' ', '')) + ')
      ) AS PivotTable'

execute(@sql)
```

Comment: Suggested reading: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx and https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp-executesql.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way, note that if you don't want to pass `@Startdate` from out you should change it's place too.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[project_revenue_forecast_monthly]
@startDate datetime,

AS

Declare @sql varchar(max)
.....
```